# SharePoint filter Based on Startswith

Tags: sharepoint, filter

I want to filter my sharepoint list based on what letter / number a row starts with. I know I can do this by adding a new calculated column and filter on that but I would love to be able to filter solely using the URL or JavaScript without adding a column for only that purpose. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this just through the URL. SharePoint accepts FilterFieldxxx and FilterValuexxx querystring parameters, but they only filter **exact** values.

You could do it programmatically using xslt in a list view. You could also use JavaScript to call an API like Web services, listdata.svc, the JSOM, or _api (new in SP 2013). But honestly the calculated column seems to be the most solid and straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Content Editor webpart to your view form using SharePoint Designer and put in some jQuery to filter the list based on a querystring value.

Upload the jQuery files to your style library and add the javascript to your content editor webpart.

note that it will be hard to get this right as the querystring is extensivley used in views and views are very flexible and allow someone to completely redesign the output html, just by adding in a group by clause to the view or even remove your title field.